# NMaximize seems to be returning the wrong result

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to use `NMaximize` to show that entropy is maximized when the distribution is uniform. It seems to work when the random variable is valued, but breaks at 4+ variables:

```
p = {p1, p2, p3, p4};
c = Map[0 <= # <= 1 &, p];
NMaximize[{Sum[-Log[p[[i]]]*p[[i]], {i, 1, Length[p]}], Total[p] == 1,
   Splice[c]}, p]
```

If `p` is changed to `{p1, p2, p3}`, then the result is `p1 = p2 = p3 = 1/3` as expected. But for 4 probabilities, I get the following:

```
{1.30778, {p1 -> 0.3323, p2 -> 0.269063, p3 -> 0.0975481, 
  p4 -> 0.301089}}
```

Which seems clearly wrong. Am I using `NMaximize` incorrectly?

Comment: Weirdly this works using the $L_1$ norm i.e `Abs[p1] + Abs[p2] + Abs[p3] + Abs[p4]` by doing - `NMaximize[{Total[-# Log[#] & /@ p], Splice[c], Norm[p, 1] == 1}, p]` and gives the result: `{1.38629, {p1 -> 0.250001, p2 -> 0.25, p3 -> 0.25, p4 -> 0.25}}` but note the slight error of .000001 which violates the constraint.

Comment: If you use the `"RandomSearch"` method then it gives the right result straight away: `NMaximize[{Total[-# Log[#] & /@ p], Splice[c], Total[p] == 1}, p, 
 Method -> "RandomSearch"]`

Comment: Just tell NMaximize about the symmetry  `NMaximize[{Sum[-Log[p[[i]]]*p[[i]], {i, 1, Length[p]}], Total[p] == 1,
    p1 == p2 == p3 == p4, c} // Flatten, p] `  . This works also with Maximize  `Maximize[{Sum[-Log[p[[i]]]*p[[i]], {i, 1, Length[p]}], Total[p] == 1, 
   p1 == p2 == p3 == p4, c} // Flatten, ` yields `{Log[4], {p1 -> 1/4, p2 -> 1/4, p3 -> 1/4, p4 -> 1/4}} `

Comment: @flinty The L1 norm trick doesn't seem to generalize if I add more parameters, but RandomSearch seems to work well consistently.

Comment: @Akku14 the symmetry is something I knew about the nature of the solution in this case. It's not going to help me in other situations where the probabilities are going to be different

Comment: @flinty - I recommend using arbitrary-precision for the calculation: `NMaximize[{Total[-p Log[p]], Splice[c], Norm[p, 1] == 1}, p, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N`

Comment: @rgrinberg - The approach recommended by @flinty works for up to 7 items with `WorkingPrecision -> 20`. `WorkingPrecision -> 25` extends this to 10 items. Presumably, larger values of `WorkingPrecision` can handled additional items.

Comment: @BobHanlon Interesting. For 10 variables, Mathematica is unable to find the solution even with `WorkingPrecision -> 45`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

p = {p1, p2, p3, 1 - p1 - p2 - p3};

sol = Solve[Thread[D[Total[-p*Log[p]], {Most@p}] == 0], Most@p]

(* {{p1 -> 1/4, p2 -> 1/4, p3 -> 1/4}} *)

p /. sol[[1]]

(* {1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4} *)

Total[-p*Log[p]] /. sol[[1]]

(* Log[4] *)
```

**EDIT:** For larger number of probabilities

```
n = 50;

p = pr /@ Range[n - 1];
p = Append[p, 1 - Total[p]];

sol = Solve[Thread[D[Total[-p*Log[p]], {Most@p}] == 0], Most@p];

(p /. sol[[1]] // Union) == {1/n}

(* True *)

(Total[-p*Log[p]] /. sol[[1]]) == Log[n]

(* True *)
```

Comment: That works alright, but it's a little manual. I would prefer to use mathematica's native optimization functions.